# Powershell not reading .txt lines

Tags: powershell

I cannot get PowerShell to run this .txt file, what am I doing wrong? I tried changing the name of the .txt and checked passed scripts and everything seems to be the same but I keep getting an error saying that the ".txt in invalid"

```
$POSName = "$PSScriptRoot\Bex.txt"

foreach ($POS in (Get-Content $POSName)) {
    $Bex = Get-Service -ComputerName $POSName | Where-Object { $_.name -eq "BexServ" }
}

If ($Bex -eq $null) {
    # Service does not exist
    Write-Host " doesn't exist." -ForegroundColor Red
} 
Else {
    # Service does exist
    Write-Host "The $($Bex.Name) service found." -ForegroundColor Green
           
    If ($Bex.Status -eq "Running") {
        # Stop Service
        Set-Service -status stopped -ComputerName $POSName -name $Box.Name -ErrorAction Stop

        Write-Host "The $($Bex.Name) successfully stopped."  -ForegroundColor Green 
    }
    else {
        #service already stopped
        If ($Bex.Status -eq "Stopped") {
            Write-Host "The $($Bex.Name) service already Stopped." -ForegroundColor Green
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and paste the _exact_ error message. Add text, not a screenshot. Do not type but use copy-paste to avoid typos.

Comment: You're trying to use `Get-Service` with parameter `-ComputerName` being a file path.. ($POSName). Use variable `$POS` there. While you're at it, move all code `if (..) else {..}` **inside** the loop

Answer (score 0):

As commented, you are using the wrong variable in the loop. The code is reading the text file just fine, it is `Get-Service` that cannot deal with a path to a file in the `-ComputerName` parameter.

Also, the placing of the `if..else` should be **inside** the loop, not after.

Try

```
$POSName = "$PSScriptRoot\Bex.txt"

foreach ($POS in (Get-Content $POSName)) {
    $Bex = Get-Service -ComputerName $POS | Where-Object { $_.name -eq "BexServ" }

    If (!$Bex) {
        # Service does not exist
        Write-Host " doesn't exist." -ForegroundColor Red
    } 
    Else {
        # Service does exist
        Write-Host "The $($Bex.Name) service found." -ForegroundColor Green
           
        If ($Bex.Status -eq "Running") {
            # Stop Service
            Set-Service -status stopped -ComputerName $POSName -name $Box.Name -ErrorAction Stop

            Write-Host "The $($Bex.Name) successfully stopped."  -ForegroundColor Green 
        }
        else {
            #service already stopped
            If ($Bex.Status -eq "Stopped") {
                Write-Host "The $($Bex.Name) service already Stopped." -ForegroundColor Green
            }
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>It might also be a good idea to output the computername (`$POS`) in the `Write-Host` lines too</sup>